# Caps-lock indication with conky

Tags: xubuntu, conky

I have laptop without Caps Lock indicator.
I'd like to have this indicator in conky.
Which conky option can help me to get status of Caps-Lock?

- OS: Xubuntu 12.04.
- Conky 1.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{color ffff00}${exec xset q | grep "Caps Lock:   on" | awk '{print $4}'}${color}
```

works for me.

Please note that having too many `exec` in your Conky *could* increase demand on your system resources.

Also, how soon you see "on" depends on the frequency of updating. In other words, it will depend on the value you have set. I update every two seconds:

```
update_interval 2.0
```

You may also want to position where "on" appears but that will depend on the rest of your Conky code. For example, what values of `gap_x` and `gap_y` you set. I have my minimal Conky at the top of the screen and I use

```
gap_x 3
gap_y 4
```

along with

```
${goto 500}
```

prepended to the the actual code so that "on" appears near the top center of my screen.

Comment: Very nice! I tweaked it a bit to have:

${execpi 1 xset q | grep "Caps Lock:" | awk '{if ($4 == "on") {print "${blink ${color red}ON${color}}"} else {print "OFF"}}'}