# I need to know when the "Caps Lock " key is turned on/off

Tags: indicator, capslock

I need to know when the "Caps Lock " key is turned on.

Does Ubuntu has a visual indicator to show me when the key "Caps Lock" is on?

Comment: also possible beside the dupe: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2014/05/23/caps-lock-indicator-ubuntu-1404/

Comment: Also http://askubuntu.com/a/567887/248158 (self-promotion)?

Answer (score 1):

I needed a visual indicator on my screen since my laptop didn't have any such indicator. My solution might address your question.

1) add the program indicator-keylock by entering the following command in a terminal

`sudo apt install indicator-keylock` 
enter your password when prompted - no text will be displayed as you type your password

2) add this program to your computer's start up programs.